# How to run my mongoose .find code synchronously with es6 promises?

Tags: mongoose, ecmascript-6, synchronous

I want to run this code synchronously, how can I do that with promises?

```
  var homePosts = {};

  Post.find({}, function (err, posts) {
    if (err) {
      req.flash('error', 'An unknown error has occurred.');
      res.redirect('back');
    } else {
      homePosts.newest = posts;
    }
  }).limit(4).sort( { date : -1 } );
```

and after finding them run:

```
  res.render("home", {homePosts});
```

Comment: You cannot. Perform the render after the async operation is complete.

Comment: Promises don't make your synchronous. They just provide a unified interface for handling asychronous APIs.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how can I run my code synchronously?